# Finding extreme values of a deltoid curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, parametric

Take a look at hypocycloids (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid). If the larger circle has a radius of three times the radius of the smaller circle, a deltoid is created. Here, we consider a deltoid.

**Calculating the parametric equations for $x(θ)$ and $y(θ)$ after simplification with $R = 3r$.**

$$x(\theta)=2r\cos\theta+r\cos2\theta 
\quad\hbox{and}\quad 
y(\theta)=2r\sin\theta-r\sin2\theta.$$

How long does it take the small circle to walk along the complete larger circle?**

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Angle $\theta$ in your parametric equation is nothing but the angle in polar coordinates. As the curve divides $2\pi$ into three equal parts, it is clear that it has cusps at $\theta=0, 2\pi/3, 4\pi/3$ and crosses $x$-axis at $\theta=\pi$.

Comment: And to calculate $x$ and $y$ values, just plug the value of $\theta$ into your formulas for $x(\theta)$ and $y(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer only your 4th question, for the others see my comment above. If $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the small circle, then its center moves with linear velocity $v=\omega r$. On the other hand, the center goes once around a circle of radius $2r$, so the time it takes is
$$
T={4\pi r\over v}={4\pi \over \omega }=2\tau,
$$
where $\tau=2\pi/\omega$ is the time needed for the small circle to make a complete turn around itself.